# SQL procedure with multiple statements

Tags: sql

I have little SQL experience, so this question may be a bit obvious, but from what I've read, it seems I am using BEGIN/END correctly. I'm using BEGIN/END in order to have multiple statements execute consecutively. The goal is to delete the previous 'winner' from the table, then calculate and populate the table with a new 'winner'. The table should only ever have one record; the winner.  no matter how the statements are structured, I can't get it to process anything past the first valid statement.

```
create procedure contest.getWinner()
begin
    begin
        delete from contest.winner
        where stars > 0;
    end

    begin
    insert into contest.winner(img, stars, cur_DT)
        (SELECT A.img, A.stars, now()
            FROM
            ( 
                SELECT 
                    I.img, 
                    SUM(I.stars) as stars,
                    MIN(I.cur_DT) as TieBreaker
                FROM 
                    contest.votes as I 
                GROUP BY I.img
            )as A
            ORDER BY
            A.stars DESC, 
            A.TieBreaker 
            limit 1
        );
    end
end
```

Comment: Which db engine? Do you get any error?

Comment: have you tried to remove inner begin/end?

Comment: i'm using MySql on win7, and editing in MySql Workbench.  i've tried every permutation of begin/end, including labels, and 'begin try', nested begin/end, single outter most begin/end, etc...

Answer (score 2):

this should work for MsSql server

```
create procedure getWinner
as

begin
    delete from contest.winner
    where stars > 0;
end

begin
insert into contest.winner(img, stars, cur_DT)
    (SELECT A.img, A.stars, GETDATE()
        FROM
        ( 
            SELECT 
                I.img, 
                SUM(I.stars) as stars,
                MIN(I.cur_DT) as TieBreaker
            FROM 
                contest.votes as I 
            GROUP BY I.img
        )as A
        ORDER BY
        A.stars DESC, 
        A.TieBreaker 
        limit 1
    );
 End
```

Answer (score 0):

If your RDBMS is SQL Server, use this syntax:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE <name>
AS
BEGIN
  <sql_statement>;
  <sql_statement>;
  <sql_statement>;
END
```

You must add the "AS" keyword before "BEGIN".

Answer (score 0):

This should work in mySQL

```
delimiter //

    create procedure contest.getWinner()
    begin
        delete from contest.winner
        where stars > 0;

        insert into contest.winner(img, stars, cur_DT)
            (SELECT A.img, A.stars, now()
                FROM
                ( 
                    SELECT 
                        I.img, 
                        SUM(I.stars) as stars,
                        MIN(I.cur_DT) as TieBreaker
                    FROM 
                        contest.votes as I 
                    GROUP BY I.img
                )as A
                ORDER BY
                A.stars DESC, 
                A.TieBreaker 
                limit 1
            );

    end; //

delimiter ;
```

The problem is that in mySQL, the ; is the delimiter character, so when the workbench sees it, it try to end the procedure.   By changing the delimiter to something else, you can then create the procedure.   Afterwards, you can restore the original statement delimiter.

Comment: notta. i'm using the latest version of MySql workbench, and am getting the same errors - 'syntax to use near '
begin

Comment: I think the . in the procedure name might be the issue.   Can you try it with Contest_GetWinner()

Comment: same error. i've successfully created other, single statement, procedures using the 'dot' notation.  no matter what i try, i can only get the first statement saved into the SP.  all other statements, either error out, or are simply not included in the SP.

Comment: Try changing the delimiter before creating the procedure, as shown in the modified code above

Comment: ha, the delimiter trick worked!  after playing around a bit, only one, outer most begin/end combo would pass.  thanks sparky!